# error with getting current week total amount from all rows with sql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple rows with each their total amount, I want to sum them up to get a single value for the current week.

I want to get the total sum amount for all rows for this current week and display it in a small widget.

```
<?php

  $query = "SELECT SUM(total_amount) as total_current_wk_amount FROM orders 
  WHERE yearweek(DATE(transaction_date), 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1)";

  $total_current_wk_amount = $heidisql->prepare($query);
  $total_current_wk_amount->execute();
  $results = $total_current_wk_amount->fetch();

  ?>

  <div class="">Total Revenue: <?php echo $results[total_current_wk_amount]; ?></div>
```

**Problem solved**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the result (by using a [`fetch`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method) instead of trying to display the statement object as a string.

```
<?php
$result = $total_current_wk_amount->fetch();
?>
<div class="">Total Revenue: <?php echo $result->total_current_wk_amount; ?></div>
```

Comment: this time im getting Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: What did you try @JOnathaFlint ? I mean : `$stmt = $heidisql->prepare($query); $stmt->execute(); $result = $stmt->fetch(); var_dump($result);`

Comment: when I echo just $result i get Array to string conversion, while $result->total_current_wk_amount i get Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: array(1) { ["total_current_wk_amount"]=> string(5) "75.00" }

Comment: So If it is an array, you have to echo `$result['total_current_wk_amount']`.

Answer (score 0):

With `execute()` you run the query, but you still have to fetch the results: `fetchAll` to get all the rows, or in case you only need one row, `fetch`. So

```
  $smtp = $heidisql->prepare($query);
  $smtp->execute();
  $row = $smtp->fetch();
```

Comment: im getting Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: is your query working when you execute it from phpmyadmin or console?

Comment: yeah, I get the sum of all my rows(total_amount)